# Refinement to this MySQL query?

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

I've got a query which is taking a long time and I was wondering if there was a better way to do it? Perhaps with joins?

It's currently taking ~2.5 seconds which is way too long.

To explain the structure a little: I have products, "themes" and "categories". A product can be assigned any number of themes or categories. The themeitems and categoryitems tables are linking tables to link a category/theme ID to a product ID.

I want to get a list of all products with at least one theme and category. The query I've got at the moment is below:

```
SELECT *
FROM themes t, themeitems ti, products p, catitems ci, categories c
WHERE t.ID = ti.THEMEID 
AND ti.PRODID = p.ID 
AND p.ID = ci.PRODID 
AND ci.CATID = c.ID
```

I'm only actually selecting the rows I need when performing the query but I've removed that to abstract a little.

Any help in the right direction would be great!

Edit: EXPLAIN below

[image: EXPLAIN]

Comment: Can you post the EXPLAIN?

Comment: How many rows is returned?

Answer (score 1):

Utilise correct JOINs and ensure there are indexes on the fields used in the JOIN is the standard response for this issue.

```
SELECT *
FROM themes t
INNER JOIN themeitems ti ON t.ID = ti.THEMEID
INNER JOIN products p ON ti.PRODID = p.ID
INNER JOIN catitems ci ON p.ID = ci.PRODID
INNER JOIN categories c ON ci.CATID = c.ID
```

The specification of the JOINs assists the query engine in working out what it needs to do, and the indexes on the columns used in the join, will enable more rapid joining.

Comment: "The specification of the JOINs assists the query engine" --- it's not. Optimizer performs your and OP's query identically (to be precise - one is rewritten into another before evaluating)

Comment: JOINs are good for readability (and ensuring one doesn't forget to add a joining condition.) But I agree, that indexes are missing here.

Comment: Also it would make sense to enumerate what indexes are required.

Comment: @zerkms I am not fully in agreement with you. If once logically think of join, and they way he wrote, then there is difference and join seems faster. In OP's queries all tables are cartisian before been filter, but in joins they are filter with every join and hence use less memory to get final result set. Also, why not practise world standard, when join are more readable and give equal or better performance.

Comment: @Sumit Gupta: "I am not fully in agreement with you" --- that's how optimizer works. Before query evaluation explicit inner joins are rewritten to implicit ones. I didn't say anything about readability, but about performance. "In OP's queries all tables are cartisian before been filter" --- it's not. How the query looks like has nothing to do with how it's performed. If necessary optimizer may even change the order of joins (and swap some `JOIN`ed tables with the one that is `FROM`ed)

Comment: @zerkms thanks for clarification, I didn't know about rewrite.

Answer (score 1):

Your query is slow because you don't have any indexes on your tables.

Try:

```
create unique index pk on themes (ID)
create index fk on themeitems(themeid, prodid)
create unique index pk on products (id)
create index fk catitems(prodid, catid)
create unique index pk on categories (id)
```

As @symcbean writes in the comments, the catitems and themeitems indices should probably be unique indices too - if there isn't another column to add to that index (e.g. "validityDate"), please add that to the create statement.

Comment: Wasn't supposed to alter the database structure at all. Is there an inverse to this so I can test it with and without?

Comment: @Michael adding index is not Altering structure, it doesn't make any different on table fields and structure, just it store information of each record seperately, same as in book's Index. the content of book remain same if index present or not [Techincally it just change the way date is stored, but you can ignore it for now].

Comment: Not sure I understand your question

Comment: the index on the themeitems and catitems table should be the primary key - not a non-unique index (indeed the proposed indexes should *all* be primary keys) and as per answer elsewhere the order of entries in themeitmes and catitems is wrong given the scope defined in the question.

Comment: @symcbean - good point. Won't affect performance much, but it's clearly the right thing to do.

Comment: @symcbean: "the order of entries in themeitmes and catitems is wrong" --- actually it's not correct. The thing is - there should be no composite indexes at all. The conditions `themeitems` and `catitems` take part in belong to *different* joins. So *in this case* the order doesn't matter since it should be 2 separate indexes.

Comment: @zerkms: the order *may* not matter for the original query proposed - indeed the order you propose may actually make this query faster - however my point was that Michael may not actually need to fetch the data from the themes and categories in which case it's possible that these tables are not required in the query. When that is the case, the optimizer will not use the indexes with foreign keys on those tables sited before the product foreign key. But if they are the other way around then the optimizer will use the indexes regardless if the 2 other tables are included.

Answer (score 0):

Your query is very simple. I do not think that your cost decreases with implementing joins. You can try putting indexes to appropriate columns

Answer (score 0):

Simply selecting less data is the glaringly obvious solution here.

Why do you need to know every column and every row every time you run the query? Addressing any one of these 3 factors will improve performance.

> I want to get a list of all products with at least one theme and category

That rather implies you don't care *which* theme and category, in which case.....

```
SELECT p.*
FROM themeitems ti, products p, catitems ci
WHERE p.ID = ti.PRODID  
AND p.ID = ci.PRODID
```

It may be possible to make the query run significantly faster - but you've not provided details of the table structure, the indexes, the volume of data, the engine type, the query cache configuration, the frequency of data updates, the frequency with which the query is run.....

**update**

Now that you've provided the explain plan then it's obvious you've got very small amounts of data **AND NO RELEVENT INDEXES!!!!!**

As a minimum you should add indexes on the product foreign key in the themeitems and catitems tables. Indeed, the primary keys for these tables should be the product id and category id / theme id, and since it's likely that you will have more products than categories or themes then the fields should be in that order in the indexes. (i.e. PRODID,CATID rather than CATID, PRODID)

**update2**

Given the requirement "to get a list of all products with at least one theme and category", it might be faster still (but the big wins are reducing the number of joins and adding the right indexes) to....

```
SELECT p.*
FROM product p
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT ti.PRODID
    FROM themeitems ti, catitems ci
    WHERE ti.PRODID=ci.PRODID
) i ON p.id=i.PRODID
```

Comment: "very small amounts of data" - multiply all the rows values and you get hundreds of millions

Comment: No - even on very fast hardware the DBMS won't process "hundreds of millions" of records in 2.5 seconds (and even then a cartesian product of hundreds of millions is not what I would describe as particularly large). And even in the absence of indexing, the joins wil be optimized as merge operations

Comment: "even on very fast hardware the DBMS won't process" --- it's a query optimizer prediction (estimation). Assume it as the upper bound. My point was: we cannot get the real numbers from the explain, since there is not enough data. So you cannot say "very small amounts of data" since the real number of rows returned may vary from 0 to 100s of millions depending on the actual data.

Comment: "I've got a query which is taking a long time....It's currently taking ~2.5 seconds". I wasn't referring to the plan.

Comment: "**Now that you've provided the explain plan then it's obvious** you've got very small amounts of data" --- "I wasn't referring to the plan" o_O Excuse me, but from the plan it's not *obvious*, it's *impossible to say*  the amounts of data being returned. I even calculated the exact number of rows as max boundary - 356,887,090,368

Comment: @zerkms: if you won't take my for it that you are mistaken about how the optimizer works then plug your numbers into a spreadsheet and work out how many memory fetches and comparison per second the value you calculated equates to. Even with data values fitting into a single register fetched from memory, that would require a processor running in excess of 1 Terra-hertz to complete the operation in 2.5 seconds.

Comment: I understand it. My point is: you either predict following by timing (not common and efficient), or by analyzing execution plan. In your answer you clearly stated "Now that you've provided the explain plan then it's obvious you've got very small amounts of data" and I just made a note that it's **NOT OBVIOUS** and not possible to say from the plan details. That simple.

Answer (score 0):

**Ive made an answer off this because i could not place it as an comment**

Basic thumb off action if you want to remove FULL table scans with JOINS.
You should index first.

**Note** that this not always works with ORDER BY/GROUP BY in combination with JOINS, because often an Using temporary; using filesort is needed.

**Extra because this is out off the scope off the question and how to fix slow query with ORDER BY/GROUP BY in combination with JOIN**

Because the MySQL optimizer thinks it needs to access the smallest table first to get the best execution what will cause MySQL cant always use indexes to sort the result and needs to use an temporary table and the filesort the fix the wrong sort ordering

(read more about this here [MySQL slow query using filesort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18738483/mysql-slow-query-using-filesort) this is how i fix this problem because using temporary really can kill performance when MySQL needs an disk based temporary table)